# Error in Click Element At Coordinates keyword using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am debugging a provided script in robot framework with the below peace of lines:-

```
*** Variables ***
${administration}   <sample xpath>   
*** Keywords ***
     Click Next Network
        Click Element At Coordinates    ${administration}   10  460
        Sleep   3
    
    Click Done Network
        Click Element At Coordinates    ${administration}   70  460
        Sleep   3
        
    Click Close Network
        Click Element At Coordinates    ${administration}   -40 460
        Sleep   3
```

While Executing the script is not working as per the coordinates provided and throwing error:-

```
MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds
```

(Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.127)

Please provide some guidelines on how can we get the correct coordinates and make this script working.

Comment: You need to post the site url and the code you are using. No one will be able to help you without this information.

Comment: Sorry for the limited information, It's the confidential webpage as well as the code. just want to check how can we debug the coordinates in the given framework.